# upload + read xml and populate fields in a form with values

Tags: c#, jquery, xml, json

Is there a way to upload an xml in c# and map the values to certain textboxes using jquery?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<AuditSheet>
<CustomerInfo>
<CustomerName></CustomerName>
<PlantSiteName></PlantSiteName>
<SystemName></SystemName>
<PhysicalAddress1></PhysicalAddress1>
<PhysicalAddress2></PhysicalAddress2>
</CustomerInfo>
</AuditSheet>
```

Comment: Why is your question tagged with `json`? What application are you talking about? ASP.NET, WinForms, Silverlight, WPF, ...? By upload you mean the user uploading something?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Because i want to convert the xml to json after ive uploaded it and place the values in different textboxes. Asp.net. "Upload an XML".

Comment: why do you want to convert the XML to JSON? Why do you need JSON in order to populate values in textboxes?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I dont have to, but i guess its easier that way.

Comment: Does the XML have a static schema? If yes, how does it look like? If not, how do you expect to perform the mapping?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Yes, static. Since the input fields have the same classname as the xml nodes they should be maped to i was planning to just itterate through them.

Comment: Could you show how a sample XML would look like?

Comment: What about the UI? You have textboxes corresponding to each node of the XML element?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? If so, you should say so in the tags.

Comment: Depending on what version of .NET you're using, it should be easier to just query the XML directly using the Linq to Xml library than to convert it int JSON. At least it would be in VB.NET, I'm assuming the same basic principles would apply in C#. In VB.NET now, using XML is CRAZY easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

youve asked a complex question with very little description of what it is exactly you want to achieve.

What I think you want to do is allow a user to upload an XML file to a webpage and then i guess using AJAX send the XML to the server and have it return JSON so you can use that to populate fields on that same page.

What you can do is create a HTTP handler (implementing IHttpHandler). Register that handler in your web.config with a specific URLfor example /services/sheetuploader.ashx.

Then define a class called AuditSheet and CustomerInfo and decorate them with a DataContract attribute and mark the members matching your AuditSheet XML elements with DataMember attributes.

Something like:

```
[DataContract]
public class AuditSheet
{
   [DataMember]
   public CustomerInfo CustomerInfo{get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class CustomerInfo
{
   [DataMember]
   public string CustomerName {get;set;}

   //rest of the members go here...
}
```

You can then use the [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) object to read the XML into an instance of your AuditSheet class. See the ReadObject method for doing that. You do this in the ProcessRequest method of your Http Handler.

After creating the object you can then serialize to JSON by using [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) and its WriteObject method.

To send back JSON to the client you add the following to the ProcessRequest method

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
context.Response.Write(ConvertToJson(auditSheet)); //auditSheet is an instance of AuditSheet read from XML
```

to send the XML to the server you can use [jQuery's AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method using a POST request.

Hope im close to what youre actually trying to do and that this can help you get started.

Yoav.